# how to display json data using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to Json data using `ng-repeat`. But the web page is either showing as white page or a blank page.

The Json:

```
{
    "questions": {
            "q1": {
                "qText": " question1",
                "result":"result1",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            },
            "q2": {
                "qText": " question2",
                "result":"result2",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            },
            "q3": {
                "qText": " question3",
                "result":"result3",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            },
            "q4": {
                "qText": " question4",
                "result":"result4",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            },
            "q5": {
                "qText": " question5",
                "result":"result5",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            },
            "q6": {
                "qText": " question6",
                "result":"result6",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions track by $index">
    <div class="q1"> 
        <p>{{question.qText}}</p>
        <input type="radio"  ng-model="qobj.q1" ng-value="'A'" ><label>{{question.options.A}}</label>
        <input type="radio"  ng-model="qobj.q1" ng-value="'N'" ><label>{{question.options.N}}</label>
        <input type="radio"  ng-model="qobj.q1" ng-value="'D'" ><label>{{question.options.D}}</label>
        <input type="radio"  ng-model="qobj.q1" ng-value="'NA'" ><label>{{question.options.NA}}</label>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: onclick submit get all input values and stored in object how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

> Check whether your questions object is in scope.

```js
angular.module("test", [])
  .controller('ctr1', function($scope) {
    $scope.save = function(ques){
      $scope.showAnswer=true;
    }
    $scope.ques = {
      "q1": {
        "qText": " question1",
        "result": "",
        "options": {
          "A": "option1",
          "N": "option2",
          "D": "otpion3",
          "NA": "option4"
        }
      },
      "q2": {
        "qText": " question2",
        "result": "",
        "options": {
          "A": "option1",
          "N": "option2",
          "D": "otpion3",
          "NA": "option4"
        }
      },
      "q3": {
        "qText": " question3",
        "result": "",
        "options": {
          "A": "option1",
          "N": "option2",
          "D": "otpion3",
          "NA": "option4"
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="ctr1">
  <form name="testForm">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="q in ques">
        {{q.qText}}
        <input type="radio" ng-model="q.result" ng-value="q.options.A" /><label>{{q.options.A}}</label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="q.result" ng-value="q.options.N" /><label>{{q.options.N}}</label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="q.result" ng-value="q.options.D" /><label>{{q.options.D}}</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="save(ques)" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <div ng-if="showAnswer">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="q in ques">
        {{q.qText}}== {{q.result}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: option 1, option2, option3 and option 4 not displaying , how we can display ?

Comment: ng-model q values how can increame like this question1-->ng-model="qobj.q1", question2--> ng-model="qobj.q2", question3-->ng-model="qobj.q3",

Comment: @sunithabg, i didnt get what you want to achieve: I have just edited the snippet and displayed the selected option at last.

Comment: all quations are need to build as object , how can i do?

Comment: ng-model="option", $scope.option it is coming undefined

Comment: onsubmit all questions answer build object like qObjection it conain all the user input values how can i do

Comment: @sunithabg, just check i have updated the code.You can keep ng-model of each input field as some property in your questions object. Here i have change it to "result"

Answer (score 0):

Your json does not contain an array, but an object with other objects. Therefore you must let angular know to iterate through its keys:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, question) in questions track by $index">
    <!-- .. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do! 
Your model says :

```
`"questions": {
            "q1": {...}
            },
            "q2": {...},
            ...
}`
```

so, questions should be an Array for ng-repeat to work with it!

Just a guess, I don't think you will need "q1", "q2" tags at all..
Modify your "questions" model to this:

```
`"questions": [
             {
                "qText": " question1",
                "result":"result1",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            },
            {...},
            {...},
            {...} 
]`
```

Remember: ng-repeat is well suited for Collections, and is not meant for Objects.

Hope this serves your purpose!