# Bind a single ng-model for 2 ng-repeat in Angular Radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, radio-button

I have two different lists, which I need to display as a single list on a page and show as a radio items in a screen. How to identify the ng-model and selected values if no element is chosen or by default if user selects the default value.

```html
<script>
   angular.module('valueExample', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.names = ['pizza', 'unicorns', 'robots'];
       $scope.my = { favorite: 'unicorns' };
     }]);
</script>
 <form ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <h2>Which is your favorite?</h2>
     <label ng-repeat="name in names" for="{{name}}">
       {{name}}
       <input type="radio"
              ng-model="my.favorite"
              ng-value="name"
              id="{{name}}"
              name="favorite">
     </label>
   <label ng-repeat="name in names2" for="{{name}}">
       {{name}}
       <input type="radio"
              ng-model="my.favorite"
              ng-value="name"
              id="{{name}}"
              name="favorite">
     </label>
   <div>You chose {{my.favorite}}</div>
 </form>
```

names and names2 are 2 list items, which i want to display on single screen

Comment: You can check my answer over here ,  I think it is inline with your requirement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028135/how-to-display-json-data-using-ng-repeat/42028450?noredirect=1#comment71294878_42028450

Comment: In second array also I need radio buttons and it should be displayed.

Comment: You can concat both lists initially and use ng-repeat on the final list

Comment: Thats not possible in my case as I have a separate headers for the two and different styles need to be applied

Comment: Add a `style` attribute to the objects with whatever value and set `ng-class` based on that.

Comment: This sounds better.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I suggested, you can concat lists and use ng-repeat  accordingly. Or you can use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end and render accordinly.

```js
 angular.module('valueExample', [])
   .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
     var names1 = ['pizza1', 'unicorns1', 'robots1'];
     var names2 = ['pizza2', 'unicorns2', 'robots2'];
     $scope.names = names1.concat(names2);
     $scope.my = {
       favorite: 'unicorns1'
     };
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="valueExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <h2>Which is your favorite?</h2>
  <div ng-repeat="name in names">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="my.favorite" ng-value="name" />
    <label>{{name}}</label>
  </div>

  <div>You chose {{my.favorite}}</div>
</form>
```